# Adding class to <td> and <tr> in Vuetify data-table？

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
 <v-data-table
      class="elevation-1 user-table"
      :headers="table.headers"
      :items="usersList"
      :items-per-page="table.options.itemsPerPage"
      :no-data-text="table.options.noDataText"
      :footer-props="table.options.footerProps"
    >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td class="text-xs-right pa-4">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right pa-0">{{ props.item.username }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right pa-0">{{ props.item.createdAt }}</td>
      </template> 
  
</v-data-table>
```

i try to use the  slot="items" to change the class of td in vuetify table ,but it doesnt work?

i use this version of vuetify

- "vuetify": "^2.3.17",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refactor item slot to this

```
<v-data-table
  class="elevation-1 user-table"
  :headers="table.headers"
  :items="usersList"
  :items-per-page="table.options.itemsPerPage"
  :no-data-text="table.options.noDataText"
  :footer-props="table.options.footerProps"
>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-xs-right pa-4"> {{ item.id }} </td>
      <td class="text-xs-right pa-0"> {{ item.username }} </td>
      <td class="text-xs-right pa-0"> {{ item.createdAt }} </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

whats wrong with your code:

1. you used `items` instead of `item` => `<template slot="item" slot-scope="props">`
2. you missed `tr` element

Comment: thanks ，your answer is right. i have change my codes. and otherwise,do you know how to change the text size using vuetify?

Comment: @radiorz in case of changing font size of vuetify components you can override component sass variables. [documentation of v-data-table sass variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#sass-variables)